# Not getting first click on XNA

Tags: xna, click, mouse

I am developing an XNA game. I am getting the mouse click in classical way. But when I run the game on emulator, everytime I cannot get any response on my first click on the screen. Other clicks work as normal. Is it a loading problem or what?
Thank you.

Comment: Silly question, but is the emulator running in window mode on a PC?

Comment: is it possible your first click is just giving the emulator the cpu's focus and subsequent clicks are being applied to your app?

Comment: Why is it a silly question? For buttons on my app it is a bug. When I use the Touch Collection, it gets the first click. But it is not a reliable way than mouse click because of moved states.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your game? Maybe you are detecting mouse click state twice and the first click is lost for that reason. You should add your code.

Comment: Very hard to offer help if you aren't showing us how exactly you're tracking mouse clicks!

Answer (score 0):

For the help, It's running on device without the bug. It's just a emulator bug.